# What is the file format of .dav file / How to read a .dav file in java

Tags: dav-file

I have a .dav file from a security camera (CP Plus).

DAV files are created by a DVR365 digital video recorder, and are used for recording video captured by CCTV cameras. These files incorporate modified MPEG compression and are saved in an encrypted format. [More Info](http://www.openthefile.net/extension/dav)

I need to reverse engineer a .dav file so as to enable me to read the same. 
Does anybody know the structure of a .dav file ?
Further, is there any tool in linux which can convert a .dav file to a standard format like mp4/avi/mov/flv ... etc.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  If so can you post an answer?

Comment: There is a converter available here   http://www.bahamassecurity.com/cctvforum/forum_posts.asp?TID=441&title=dahua-avi-convert-334-dav-convert  But this is not for free. As far as i remember it comes around 100 USD (not very sure)

Comment: Thanks Soumya, I'll check into it.

Answer (score 0):

I know a DAV converter that can convert DAV videos to AVI and other formats: http://www.videoconverterfactory.com/tips/dav-converter.html
But this program can be installed on windows computers. So if you have a windows computer, you can take this one.

Also, there are some DAV file players over there, which can play and convert this sort of videos to AVI format. You can download the default DAV file player provided by the company which produces the cameras that record the videos as DAV format. As far as I know, you can take DVR365 Player Software, Dahua Smart Player, Amcrest Smart Player and more. Here's an example: https://support.amcrest.com/hc/en-us/articles/206649037-Amcrest-Smart-Player-1080P-HD-CVI-

Besides, handbrake is able to convert some DAV videos to MP4 by the test. So share with you.